# Play 2.4.0 https support - RSA no longer available?

Tags: https, playframework-2.0, rsa, netty

Sorry for the horribly long stack trace but I suspect it will be asked for eventually to get to the bottom of this.

Upgraded to play 2.4.0 from prior version which (still) works on the same server.

We know that `.keystore` file is valid (I copied it in case there was any sort of file locking issue with other processes but when that didn't work I shut down the running instance and used that and yet still no joy)

Update: If we RUN activator it works - however if we START activator it does not. Will continue to investigate the relevance of that new nugget of knowledge.

> Update (2016/01/01) I have installed the certificate on dev
>   workstation to attempt to troubleshoot this further and sadly https
>   refuses to run under OS X with yet another horrible long and virtually
>   meaningless (as in no real error being pointed out) stack trace.

```
[error] - play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory - cannot load SSL context
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createScalaSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:96) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:32) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory.liftedTree1$1(NettyServer.scala:113) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory.sslEngineProvider$lzycompute(NettyServer.scala:112) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory.sslEngineProvider(NettyServer.scala:111) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory.getPipeline(NettyServer.scala:90) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.registerAcceptedChannel(NioServerBoss.java:134) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.process(NioServerBoss.java:104) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error loading HTTPS keystore from /usr/share/play/.keystore
    at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.createSSLContext(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:47) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.<init>(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:21) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyManagerFactory not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.java:137) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.createSSLContext(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:42) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
[error] - play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:89) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
[error] - play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:89) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:554) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:81) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:54) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.closeRequested(SimpleChannelHandler.java:334) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleDownstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:260) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.handleDownstream(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:106) [com.typesafe.netty.netty-http-pipelining-1.1.4.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:812) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:206) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:66) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelHandler.java:156) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:130) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:153) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:377) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:525) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:48) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyHandlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:658) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:566) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
[error] - play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:89) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
[error] - play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:89) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:554) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:81) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:54) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.closeRequested(SimpleChannelHandler.java:334) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleDownstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:260) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.handleDownstream(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:106) [com.typesafe.netty.netty-http-pipelining-1.1.4.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:812) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:206) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:66) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelHandler.java:156) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:130) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:153) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:377) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:525) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:48) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyHandlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:658) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:566) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [io.netty.netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
```

Comment: The same problem appears under `testProd` -- I suspect it has something to do with the way params are passed -- we've tried using the quoted syntax to pass the entire set of params to the (yes now deprecated) `start` or `testProd` command but still failing.

Comment: This trace appears only once an actual https page is requested -- not before - http pages can be requested without a problem -- in other words the server IS running.

Comment: I'm still searching for an answer on this - was amused to find a google search lead me back to my own question and din;t realize I had asked it until i got to the bottom and saw my own name. (sigh). There might be a hint of want is happening here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/ip6cT70VjZ4/I5cHNv0rOWkJ however that doesn't answer why on production servers.

Comment: This: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-play-tls-example/blob/master/README.md may shed some light on what needs to be done. Currently investigating. Posting it here as it took me this long to find it.

Comment: The github URL in the previous comment gave me enough hints that I eventually managed to get this problem solved. Better late then never right? I'm going to see what I can do to answer my own question but I'll need to start a clean paper trail (new certificate) to ensure I've captured all the details in the correct and portent order. FYI Play will work with wildcard certs and process is essentially the same.